# Shared folder can't be "added to My Drive"

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-shared-folder, google-drive-folder

I have two google accounts, call them A and B.  A shared a folder, call it A-Drive, with B.  B should be able to do an "Add to My Drive" -- but that action is not available.  How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

You can add just a shortcut (from 3/2020). There is a workaround: you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and old the feature appears. You can add the shared folder to your Drive (works also in Google Sync).

More info [here](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/36201091?hl=en).

Comment: This still works, not sure why was it downvoted.

Comment: Incredible! I can't believe that this is there as a hidden feature. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be caused by having a situation where A and B had both been logged in in the same browser at some point in recent memory.  Here's the procedure I finally found to solve this problem:

Use two different browsers for this work, e.g. Opera and Chrome.

- In Browser A, log in as B, then log out; now log in as A.
- In Browser B, log in as A, then log out; now log in as B.
- Unshare the A-Drive folder and save.  Now share it again.

Now you can go to Browser B and do "Add to My Drive" for the A-Drive folder.

Comment: you can do it too with incognito mode window - no need for 2 different browsers

Comment: @user0 - do you want to write an answer, or put a link in a comment?  I've never done incognito mode, sounds intriguing.

Comment: not sure if its worth to be an answer. just press CTRL+SHIFT+N in chrome/opera or CTRL+SHIFT+P in firefox

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The way I fixed it is by changing the ownership of the shared folder from A to B. After that it appeared in Google Drive of B automatically. And if You change ownership back from B to A - it will still be in Google Driver B.